# Swapping event handlers between DOM elements d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The code I have means to take a control's event handlers and move those handlers to another element and remove the previous control's event handlers fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pydty4bq/

```
var slider = d3.select('#slider1');
        var slider1Config = {
            element: slider,
            drag:function(e){
                if(d3.event.toElement)
                    console.log('has toElement',d3.event.toElement.valueAsNumber);
                else
                    console.log(d3.event.sourceEvent.srcElement.valueAsNumber);
            },
            dragstart:function(){console.log('dragstart!');},
            dragend: function(){ console.log('dragend!');}
        }
        var _drag = new Drag(slider1Config);
        _drag.element(d3.select('#slider2'));
```

the `_drag.element` function should remove the event handlers from slider1 and place them on slider2.  Currently, both elements are firing event handlers.

//drag functionality

```
var Drag = (function(){
    var _opts,
        _drag = d3.behavior.drag();
    var eventList = ['drag','dragstart','dragend'];
    function attachEvents(opts){
        eventList.forEach(function(e,i){
            if(opts[e]){
                _drag.on(e,this[e]);
            }
            else{
                _drag.on(e,null);
            }
        }.bind(this));
    };
    function detachEvents(){
        eventList.forEach(function(e,i){
            if(_opts[e]){
                _drag.on(e,null);
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
    function Drag(opts){
        _opts = opts;
        attachEvents.call(this,opts);
        _opts.element = opts.element.call(_drag);
        _opts.element.attr('isDraggable',true);
    }
  Drag.prototype.drag = function(args){
      _opts.drag(args);
  };
  Drag.prototype.dragstart = function(args){
      _opts.dragstart(args);
  }

  Drag.prototype.dragend = function(args){
      _opts.dragend(args);
  }
  Drag.prototype.element = function(el){
      if(el){
          detachEvents.call(this)
          _opts.element = el;
          attachEvents.call(this,_opts);
          _opts.element.call(_drag);
      }
  }
  Drag.prototype.config = function(opts){
      _opts = opts;
      attachEvents.call(this,_opts);

  }
    return Drag;
})();
```

What's wrong with `detachEvents` that it doesn't remove event listeners from the previous element?

Comment: by the way, currently, your _opts and _drag objects will be over-written every time you do a `new Drag`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the drag behavior works.

First you create the behavior like:

```
var _drag = d3.behavior.drag();
```

Then you attach event handlers to it:

```
_drag
    .on('dragstart', function() { ... })
    .on('drag', function() { ... })
    .on('dragend', function() { ... });
```

Then you attach this behavior to an element:

```
d3.select('#slider1').call(_drag);
```

which effectively attaches the handlers defined above to that element (actual events are named differently).

Detaching an event handler from the behavior is done like so:

```
 _drag.on('dragstart', null);
```

and it works correctly.

**BUT**

Unfortunately applying this behavior with a disabled event handler to an element with bound (enabled) event handler won't disable the element's handler. I.e.

```
_drag.on('dragstart', null);
d3.select('#slider1').call(_drag);
```

won't prevent `#slider1` from handling `dragstart` as before.

That's what my experiments have shown. Don't know whether it's a bug or not.

Anyway, there's a direct way to detach the drag handlers from an element.
As all drag-related events are located inside the `.drag` namespace, you can disable them all at once like so:

```
d3.select('#slider1').on('.drag', null);
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/crt5qr57/)

Comment: would you be kind enough to "re-factor" this statement? "Unfortunately applying this behavior with a disabled event handler to an element with bound (enabled) event handler won't disable the element's handler." I'm very interested in your answer but I can't understand what you mean there. e.g. can you define "a disabled event handler"; "bound (enabled) event handler"... maybe that would help.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I mean this: you define a behavior, then bind an event handler to it, then apply this behavior to an object => the object now has an event handler attached to it. Now you disable that event handler (```.on('event', null)```) for the behavior, and apply this behavior to the same object => the object still has previously attached handler.

Comment: Ahh ok, I think I finaly get what your saying. The event is removed from the dispatcher closured inside the "behaviour" but the call-back, which is stored on the node, is still listening.

Comment: I would say this is definitely a bug. The code around this process is (to my unsophisticated eye) horrendously convoluted and I'd like to understand it, but the listener should be properly cleaned up I would have thought.

Comment: Nice insight on the namespace by the way. It's interesting to note that, although all listeners in a namespace can be removed, listening to all events in a namespace is not implemented.  There is a placeholder for this option in the branching though, prima facie, it should be straight-forward to add an `addAll` option in `d3_selection_on`.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to understand is that the drag *behavior*, which is the function returned by `d3.behavior.drag()` can be applied to any number of selections, and has no awareness of the DOM elements it is bound too.

Internally, the *behaviour* has a custom *dispatch* object which abstracts artificial events.  These events - "drag", "dragstart" and "dragend" - are completely removed from any native events originating from the DOM.  The internal *dispatch* object is simply a system for

1. Realising these abstract events
2. Managing attachment and detachment of listeners to them
3. Providing an interface for triggering the abstract events and
4. Notifying registered listeners after they are triggered

That is what you get as a result of this code...

```
var _drag = d3.behavior.drag();

_drag
    .on('dragstart', function() { ... })
    .on('drag', function() { ... })
    .on('dragend', function() { ... });
```

Note that none of the above has any reference to any DOM elements or their events and by itself, is not capable of initiating anything.  The *behavior* can't actually do anything until it is connected to the DOM UI by `selection.call(behavior)`.  This is where the *behavior* is connected to the DOM UI.  Somehow it needs to figure out that a dragstart event has occurred, it needs to abstract this from the UI events and it's done more or less like this: `selection.on({ "mousedown.drag": mousedown, "touchstart.drag": touchstart })`.

So here are two, *completely separate, native events* - "mousedown" and "touchstart" - originating from the DOM elements in the selection - that are applied "under the hood" by the drag *behavior*.

> (As mentioned by @dekkard, they are namespaced by appending ".drag" to
>   their standard names.  d3 manages this and strips them off before
>   subscribing.)

The listeners - `mousedown` and `touchstart` are objects generated by and closured inside the `d3.behavior.drag` object and both of them call back to the the process inside the *behaviour* object which initiates the drag process.  As long as the *behavior* instance continues to exist, it will continue listening to these DOM UI events.

So there are two completely separate interfaces: one for invoking and managing the abstracted "drag", "dragstart" and "dragend" events and one for connecting to the DOM UI events "mousedown" and "touchstart".

The net effect of this code, therefore...

```
  detachEvents.call(this)
  _opts.element = el;
  attachEvents.call(this,_opts);
  _opts.element.call(_drag);
```

is to detach and re-attach the listeners to the internal *dispatch* object of the *behavior* and add the *behavior* to a second selection.  So now, a "mousedown" and "touchstart" from either selection will result in the same drag behavior.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/894), the method provided by @dekkard - `.on('.drag', null)` - is the only way to disconnect the *behavior* from the selection, so it's not a bug after all.  It's just a missing feature I guess.

Note: It would be quite easy to implement this in d3 by replacing this code...

```
function drag() { 
    this.on("mousedown.drag", mousedown).on("touchstart.drag", touchstart);
}
```

with this...

```
function drag(selection, remove) {
    [{e:"mousedown.drag", l: mousedown},{e: "touchstart.drag", l: touchstart}]
    .reduce(function (s, b) {return s = s.on(b.e, remove ? null : b.l)}, this)
}
```

in d3.behavior.drag
Then we could do this...

```
_opts.element.call(_drag, "remove")
```

to disconnect the *behavior*.